# Get the number of returned data in $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using jQuery's `$.post()` to bring data. IT returns data as

```
[{"ab":"item1"},{"ab":"item2"}]
```

My question is, how do I get the number of received data in the return function? I want to use it in a for loop.

```
$.post('add.php',
    { },
    function(data){ 
       //var tot = how to get the number of data received ?
       for(i = 1; i<tot; i++){
       }
    }
);
```

Comment: `data.length`  i think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `data` is a regular array, you can use `length`

```
$.post('add.php',
    { },
    function(data){ 
       var tot = data.length;
       for(i = 1; i<tot; i++){
       }
    }
);
```